# Is lisp really the first interpreted high-level programming language?

Tags: lisp, programming-languages, interpreted-language

Lisp is known to be the first high-level interpreted programming language appearing in 1958.

Quoting from [Interpreter (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)#:%7E:text=The%20first%20interpreted%20high%2Dlevel,on%20an%20IBM%20704%20computer.):

> The first interpreted high-level language was Lisp. Lisp was first
> implemented in 1958 by Steve Russell on an IBM 704 computer.

But, there are older high-level programming languages, that were interpreted as well such as:

- [Short Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Code_(computer_language)): appeared in 1950. Quoting from Wikipedia:

> The language was interpreted and ran about 50 times slower than
> machine code.

- [Speedcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedcoding): developed by John W. Backus (the creator of Fortran) in 1953 for the IBM 701. Quoting from Wikipedia:

> The speedcoding system was an interpreter and focused on ease of use
> at the expense of system resources.

Is it the case that lisp is the first **successful** high-level interpreted programming language? Why is it particularly that people consider being the first interpreted language?

Comment: I think that this is clearly opinion-based: what's 'high-level'?

Comment: SpeedCode is not what anyone today would call "high-level" – a more appropriate term would be "interpreted assembly language specific to the IBM 701". Also, ShortCode like `07Y10204X1Y1 0000X30309X1` may represent expressions rather than machine instructions, but high-level? Perhaps in 1950, but not any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the answer depends on the definition of a "[*high-level programming language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language)". Even though Wikipedia *does* call [Speedcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedcoding) such, the description gives no indication that it provided

> strong abstraction from the details of the computer.

All it apparently offered were

> pseudo-instructions for common mathematical functions: logarithms, exponentiation, and trigonometric operations

which is a far cry from sophisticated language constructs (functions, loops, conditionals) that are commonly associated with "*high-level*".

That said, this question probably belongs on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).